# Determining span, is there an easier way to remember it?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, span

As I understand it, to set up a problem to determine if the vector spans $
\mathbb{R}^n$ or if the given vector is in the Span of $$(v_1,v_2,...,v_n)$$
you take the vector and set up an augmented matrix that is equal to the vector $w$. (I'm not quite sure the meaning of the vector $w$ as it pertains to the vector $v$). Then row reduce.
After that I am lost. I'm looking for a way to simplify this concept and the steps it takes to get there.

Comment: A vector $w$ is in the Span of $(v_1,v_2,\cdots ,v_n)$ if you can find some scalars $a_1,\cdots ,  a_n$ so that $w= a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + \cdots + a_n v_n.$ Indeed, to show that $w$ is in your vector space you need to prove that such a family of $(a_i)$ exists. The row reduction principle helps you solve the system of equations.

Comment: So if I have two vectors and I want to find three other vectors that are in the span of the two vectors, I take the two vectors and write them in an augmented matrix, which I then row reduce. After I row reduce I solve the system of equations to find a1, a2,...an if they exist?
@gjvyu72

Comment: When you are row reducing your matrix, you are actually trying to make you set of vectors that are generating your vectore space simpler, you are basically finding a new basis that span the same vector space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a finite subset $V\subset\mathbb R^n$, say $V=\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$, a vector $b$ is in the span of $V$ if there exist scalars $c_1,\ldots,c_m$ such that
$$ b = c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_mv_m.$$ This is equivalent to whether there exists a solution to $Ax=b$, where $A$ has columns $v_1, \ldots, v_m$. Note that elementary row operations do not change the column space of a matrix, so it suffices to compute the row echelon form of the augmented matrix $[A|b]$. Then $Ax=b$ has a solution if and only if there is no row of the form $$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&\cdots&0&|&b_j\end{bmatrix}$$
in the row echelon form of $[A|b]$.